# Bazel: ttl for an artefact

Tags: bazel

I am writing a bazel rule, and one of the steps is acquiring an authentication token that will expire in some time. When I rebuild this target after that time, the step sees that nothing regarding getting that token has changed, so bazel uses a cached token.

Is there a way to take the TTL of that token into account? Or at least force that step to be rebuilt every time the build is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that you actively want to write a rule that breaks `bazel`s hermeticity guarantees.

I would advise to generate the authentication token outside of `bazel` and inject it into the build. There are several options to inject your secret:

- using `--action_env=SECRET=$TOKEN` as a command-line argument (possibly via a generated `.bazelrc`). This has the downside of invalidating your entire `bazel` cache as every rule has to re-execute when the token changes.
- generate a `secret.bzl` somehere containing a `SECRET="..."` line that you can `load()` where you need it.

If you don't want to generate the token outside of `bazel`, you can write a custom [`repository_rule()`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/globals#repository_rule(implementation,%20attrs,%20local,%20environ,%20configure,%20remotable,%20doc)) that generates a `load()`able file:

```py
def _get_token_impl(repository_ctx):
    repository_ctx.file(
        "BUILD.bazel",
        "",
        executable = False,
    )
    repository_ctx.file(
        "secret.bzl",
        "SECRET = {}".format("..."),
        executable = False,
    )

get_token = repository_rule(
    implementation = _get_token_impl,
    local = True,  # important
)
```

The `local = True` here is important:

> Indicate that this rule fetches everything from the local system and should be reevaluated at every fetch.